# Combining Viewbox, Canvas, ItemsPanelTemplate and ItemsPresenter in a user control inheriting from ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, itemscontrol, itemspresenter

I want to extend `ItemsPanel` so that I can display a "layered" visual structure where I have a "frame" with a known size and a lot of overlays, similar to what a cartographic or illustration application would be.

The problem I am having is to find out how to combine things so that everything works as expected. What I have done so far:

- Created a control which inherits from `ItemsControl`;
- Inside the control, put a `Viewbox` containing an `ItemsPresenter`
- In the control's Resources, created a Style targeting its own type, setting the `ItemsPanel` to an ItemsTemplate consisting of a `Canvas`.

So I would expect that, under Live Tree Inspection, I should see, in a nested structure:

- LayerContainer (the class name of my control)

  - ViewBox

    - ItemsPresenter
    - Canvas

      - Item1
      - Item2

Instead, what I see is this:

- LayerContainer

  - Border

    - ItemsPresenter
    - Canvas

      - Viewbox
      - Item1
      - Item2

So the problem is that the ViewBox is contained inside Canvas, alongside the rendered items.

My question then would be: how do I structure my LayerContainer control in a way that the nesting order is ItemsPresenter->Viewbox->Canvas->Items?

Here is my control (the name is not actually `LayerContainer`)

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Miotec.PressureMapping.UserControls.BaroLayerContainer"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Miotec.PressureMapping.UserControls"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:BaroLayerContainer">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="{Binding Parametros.Colunas}"
                                Height="{Binding Parametros.Linhas}"
                                IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" x:Name="container">
        <ItemsPresenter
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=container}"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=container}"/>
    </Viewbox>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a working example of how to do this then check out my [Perfy editor on GitHub](https://github.com/Myndale/Perfy), the relevant part is in [the MainWindow.xaml file](https://github.com/Myndale/Perfy/blob/master/src/MainWindow.xaml). It also shows how to implementing zoom and scrolling (if you want to support both then you don't actually need a ViewBox, just a ScrollViewer parent and a LayoutTransform on the ItemsControl).

To answer your question, each item gets wrapped in a ContentPresenter, the trick is to set your Canvas position on this parent item instead. ItemsControl exposes the `ItemContainerStyle` which allows you to do just that:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In particular, note that you do not need to explicitly declare an `ItemsPresenter` yourself, that's done for you by virtue of the fact that you're already using an ItemsControl to begin with. Just set your `ItemsPanel` to Canvas, set the style of the `ContentPresenter` via `ItemContainerStyle` and then use `DataTemplates` and/or triggers to specify the look of the collection items themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While everything you wrote is correct, that was not the problem I was facing. What I wanted to do was to have the ItemsPanel (which is a Canvas) _inside_ a ViewBox, which I needed to put in the right place. The original code declared the ViewBox "inside" the ItemsControl content area, where it was rendered alongside the items (that is, in the Canvas). What I needed to do was to declare a custom ControlTemplate and put the ViewBox with the ItemsPresenter inside it, and then everything worked as I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and googling, I realized that I could "override" the `Template` property of my control, with a `ControlTemplate` where I would put the `Viewbox` as root and, inside it, the ItemsPresenter. Then upon rendering, each item would be placed in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` containing the `Canvas`, assigned to the `ItemsPanel` property.

So below is the final working form. The solution principle was to set also the `Template` property (for the ViewBox) *besides* the `ItemsPanel` property (for the Canvas).

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Miotec.PressureMapping.UserControls.BaroLayerContainer"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Miotec.PressureMapping.UserControls"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Grid x:Name="container">
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" 
                        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=container}"
                        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=container}">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="{Binding Parametros.Colunas}"
                    Height="{Binding Parametros.Linhas}"
                    IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

</ItemsControl>
```